# PHP Session does not recreate after log out

Tags: php, session

Login Function:

```
// Create User Session Variable
session_start();
$_SESSION['session_id'] = $session_id;
```

Logout Function:

```
// Clear Session Variable
session_start();
unset ($_SESSION["session_id"]);
```

Test PHP File

```
// Start Session
session_start();
echo "Output Session Variables <br>";
echo "Session ID: " . $_SESSION['session_id'] . "<br>";
```

When a user first opens the browser (tried on Edge and Chrome) and logs in the test file displays a session. Then when the user logs out it displays the session is null. But if the user logs right back in the test file says the session is null. Yet the entire webapp treats the user as logged in and allows the user to see areas that are set to display only if session_id is not empty. Logging out again and back in does not fix the problem, only closing the browser does.

The final weird thing that happens is if you log in, log out and then log in and attempt to do something on the webapp that modifies the database it redirects to the login page where on successful login the test php file once again shows a session.

Clarification

This is the timeline of what happens:

1. Open Browser
2. Go to website
3. Login - $_SESSION['session_id'] = uniqid() . "_" . $user_id;
4. Open another tab and run test.php. Session ID: Random Number_UserID
5. Logout - unset ($_SESSION['session_id']); $_SESSION = array(); session_destroy(); // I tried everything
6. Log right back in and run test.php Session ID is null

Yet the webapp operates like if session_id is not null. I can Insert its value into the database.

Comment: Is the ONLY thing you place in the session the session_id? Or are you placing other values in the session array and testing those in other places in tiyr app

Comment: And out of interest what is `$session_id` and where do you get it from

Comment: Not sure I really get what you are saying. Bit about "closing browser" though... Do you want to remove PHPSESSID from the browser? Sounds like you are describing how sessions work. All you are doing is unsetting the Global value.

Comment: Maybe look at first example here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php - shows clearing global, destroying session data on disk, and delete of cookie. Three distinct things.

Comment: $session_id = uniqid() . "_" . $user_id; // I am putting that in the SESSION and only that.

Comment: Destroying a session in PHP is not immediate. It only removes the files of the session awaiting a routine to be fired by `session.gc_maxlifetime` (garbage collector). Meaning it is ill advised to use `uniqid() . "_" . $user_id` as it raises the chance of collisions. There is little reason to change the default behaviour unless you want to add more entropy. (you're doing the opposite) as it has a very small chance of reviving a destroyed session. It could be an issue in the future (not saying it is the issue at hand).

Comment: @Xorifelse fair enough. I may have to post more of the code but why does my test file show something in the session when I first log in but then on log out log back in it is null? Why isn't my login procedure setting the Session_ID again?

Comment: @NickG Just to clarify my comment, You're only changing an array index and not the session ID itself. Was just saying it because the key refers to a SID. But why you have this issue, I don't know. Open your browser and check your cookies. Closing the browser does not destroy the cookie, thus the session persists.

Comment: @Xorifelse I do not know how to choose your answer as correct but the issue seems to be resolved and I made so many changes that I am not entirely sure what really fixed it. I am storing just the user_id now. I also stopped storing 15 different things in session and anything I need I just do a db query. Now the inconsistent behavior stopped. I was getting situations where sometimes I would have to hit log out twice before the webapp logged out and the said session persistence. It was like if there were multiple concurrent sessions.